# Inside, just visible, was a baby boy, fast asleep

Tags: word-order

> Inside, just visible, was a baby boy, fast asleep.

It's quoted from 'Harry Potter' Book 1.

What's the subject of "was" and the complement of "was"?

Is it an inversion of "a baby boy was just visible."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey What's the subject of "was" and the complement of "was"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I mean, the subject complement of "was".

Comment: _Inside, [there] was a baby boy._ 'There' is an implied dummy subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Inside, just visible, was a baby boy, fast asleep.

*fast asleep* is parenthetical, and can be removed for clarity of the main sentence:

> Inside, just visible, was a baby boy.

The subject is *baby boy*, and the subject complement is *inside*, an adverb. The sentence could be rearranged:

> A baby boy was inside, just visible.